# Is there any way to redirect kafka connection through a golang app?

Tags: go, apache-kafka

What I am looking for is a way to make a golang app act as a proxy/gateway to the kafka.
I have a kafka server running at say port `localhost:1234` and a golang app at say `localhost:5000`. Whenever any client wants to connect to kafka, he should first connect to my golang service where I want to perform some validations for the user (auth + perms etc.) then redirect the connection itself to kafka.

I do not want to implement an intermediary interface which will read from connection and pass to kafka and vice versa.

How can I do this? Or what could be a better alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the kafka-proxy project already does. It is written in Go.

https://github.com/grepplabs/kafka-proxy

But in general, no, this is not a good idea since Kafka should be configured to handle its own auth, and Kafka has a round-trip network protocol; first the bootstrap connection is reached, then `advertised.listeners` are returned from the brokers themselves. In other words, your brokers need to return the proxy address and somehow tell the proxy to forward to a specific broker, not only your clients would know about it.